# Markov chain and tail $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

We consider a canonical Markov chain $(X_k)_k$ taking values in a countable set $E.$ We consider a real random variable $Y$ which is $\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\sigma\left(X_k, k \geq n\right)$-measurable.

Let $\mathcal{F}:=\sigma(X_k,k \in \mathbb{N}).$

Verify that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a unique real random variable $U_n$ such that $Y=U_n \circ \theta_n$ ($\theta_n$ denotes the shift operator).

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}.Y$ is $\sigma(X_k,k \geq n)$-measurable.

We note that $\theta_n^{-1}(\mathcal{F})=\sigma(\theta_n^{-1}\left(\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\sigma(X_k)\right)=\sigma\left(\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\theta_n^{-1}(\sigma(X_k))\right)=\sigma\left(\bigcup_{k \geq n} \sigma(X_{k})\right).$

Hence there exists $U_n$ such that $Y=U_n \circ \theta_n$ (by approximating $Y$ by simple functions).

How can we prove the uniqueness of $U_n$?

Comment: What's $\theta_n$ supposed to be? What have you tried?

Comment: What $\sigma$-algebra are the $U_n$ supposed to be measurable with respect to?

Comment: We are considering a canonical Markov chain, $U_n$ should be $\sigma(X_k,k \in\mathbb{N} )$-measurable.

Comment: What is the distribution of $X_0$? The variable $U_n$ is determined uniquely on the range of $\theta_n$, but not outside that range if $\theta_n$ is not surjective.

Comment: We are considering an arbitrary initial distribution $\mu.$